# What's the equivalent of httr::content(api_response, type="text/csv") in the new R package httr2?

Tags: r, httr, httr2

I'm trying to update my code to pull data from an API. I'm using currently the httr package, but it has been deprecated, so I want to replace my code using the httr2 package. I'm trying to download data in a data frame format. The code using httr is:

```
api_response <- httr::GET(url, httr::authenticate(user_name, password))
data <- httr::content(api_response, type="text/csv")
```

data is a data frame. How do I get the same result using httr2?

I've tried:

```
api_response <- request(url) %>% 
    req_auth_basic(user_name,
                   password) %>%
    req_perform()
```

and I get a httr2_response object and no errors. I don't know how to perform the next step of downloading the data in a data frame format.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated in an [httr2 github issue](https://github.com/r-lib/httr2/issues/180), you want to extract the contents as a string and parse it yourself explicitly with `readr::read_csv`

```
api_response <- request(url) |>
    req_auth_basic(user_name, password) |>
    req_perform() |>
    resp_body_string() |>
    readr::read_csv()
```

This was basically what `httr` was doing under the hood

Comment: Using `resp_body_string` produces NA, so when I pass the object NA to `read_csv` I get this error: `Error in if (length(res) == 0 || res == -1) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Is there another function in httr2 that I could use.

Comment: Without a reproducible example it’s impossible to say what exactly this website is doing.  Also note that httr has not been deprecated, it’s been superseded. That’s different. That means it’s not going away, it just won’t be changed or enhanced anymore.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the clarification! I really appreciate it. I was able to download the data with `data_details <- api_response |> resp_body_raw() |> readr::read_csv()`